# Why when i create sql server log in user my password chang automatically?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a sql server log in user i follow this steps:

1. open sql server management.
2. in security folder right click and select log in
3. in log in windows in general tab set this name to login filed:RAtest
4. select sql server authentication
5. set password:beh1368421
6. uncheck Enforce password policy
   every thing is good,but when i return to back i see my user password change auto!,what happen?

Comment: when you uncheck `Enforce password policy` does it also uncheck `Enforce Password expiration` and `User must change password at next login` ???

Comment: yes  my friend i uncheck all of them

Comment: are you creating a sql server login with windows login?

Comment: yes,i'm create sql server login with windows login

Comment: could it be your network policy, forcing password change ?

Comment: ok,how can i disable network policy?or how can i new pass who sql auto change?

Comment: have a look I have posted an answer to create a SQL Server login without using a windows login.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [RAtest] 
WITH PASSWORD = N'beh1368421'
   , DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master]
   , CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
   , CHECK_POLICY = OFF
GO
```

Comment: sql server so change password auto!

Comment: Now if you try to connect to your server with login `RAtest` and password `beh1368421` it should let you without any password change prompts.